# Failed to fetch when calling API Gateway from frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, frontend, api-gateway

I have a simple application. There is a Lambda function that returns a simple string as body and 200 as statusCode. I have a default API Gateway with a resource (GoalGroup) and a GET method. If I make a test at the method page, it executes correctly and displays the string that is returned from lambda. Similarly, curl test is executed and the string returned from the Lambda function is displayed.

When I try to call the lambda from the frontend code, I get an error message:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

the frontend code follows:

```
 fetch ("https://orofqutps8.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/prod/GoalGroup", {
    method: 'GET',
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert (`response:: ${response.status}`)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    
    alert('Raw response:', response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Process the data returned from the API
    console.log('API response:', data);
    alert('data:: ', JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert (`Error: ${error}`);
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

As for the CORS (thank you Erik258), I set the headers in the response from Lambda.

I ran curl to test:

```
>curl -v -X  GET https://xy.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/prod/GoalGroup
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying x.x.x.x:443...
* Connected to xx.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET /prod/GoalGroup HTTP/1.1
> Host: xx.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 9
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Sun, 31 Dec 2023 16:34:13 GMT
< x-amzn-RequestId: 62bf0657-8862-4ee0-8356-6fc28ab778b2
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dev.xy.amplifyapp.com/
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
< x-amz-apigw-id: Q0SwqHDJgi0ErXA=
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE
< X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-65919803-5fa85b542d75331b23d71e5a;Sampled=0;lineage=86fad7fc:0
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 6f7e76153b6fdf51bfdb3e81126b917c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Pop: BUD50-P1
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: h4LtIHc1Nl9jQ7L1PPPbnpcRIuETaTvZB9-g0cEPPm--NT6hJce6nA==
<
"success"* Connection #0 to host xy.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Anything wrong?

How do I fix the 'Failed to fetch' error?

Comment: Since it works fine in CURL, this is probably a CORS error.

Comment: Thanks Erik258 for the hint. I enabled the CORS for the resource. I checked GET at Access-Control-Allow-Method and entered the url of my frontend to Access.Control-Allow-Origin field, and hit Save, After clicking again on the Enable CORS button the settings are at the default, my modifications disappeared, Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like something must have been wrong.  Make sure you put the URL in the frontend with scheme, domain, and port if nonstandard.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to view the network traffic. Dig into the error response and update your post with the details.

Answer (score 1):

In the origin part of the header I had an ending slash like this:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://dev.xy.amplifyapp.com/',
```

after removing the extra slash, it works fine.
Thank you for the hints.